# When did John Cleese do this special on extremism?

Tags: monty-python

John Cleese has done this timeless special on Extremism:

[image]

The message fits today, but the clothes look about 40 years old.

My question is: **When did John Cleese do this special on extremism?**

Comment: *the clothes look about 40 years old.* – That’s what’s striking you and not that John Cleese looks about 40 years old as well (which is about 40 years fewer than now)?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft ha! Well played!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1987. Or "30 years ago" depending on who you read.

Many news sources have covered this story since Cleese tweeted it himself recently, though most just say '30 years ago'

A few sources give a year, 1987.  [Daily Express](https://www.express.co.uk/celebrity-news/1295488/john-cleese-fawlty-towers-uktv-bbc-extremists-twitter-stephen-fry-spt) is one.